# How to insert the generated GUID values in Firebase Realtime Database(web)?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, guid

I have generated the GUID values but when i click on the SUBMIT button the values is not getting stored in the Firebase Realtime Database.I could not able to find the error.Null values are getting stored in database.

Here is the code.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
    function license() {
    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x100000)
      .toString(16)
      .substring(1);
  }
         var val=license();
    document.write(val);

var myFirebase = firebase.database().ref();

    function fun(){
        var id = document.getElementById("number").value;

  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAw9IGgteG1Zis_oZ7t0V6xwgfJsiBMVZE",
    authDomain: "product-license.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://product-license.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "product-license",
    storageBucket: "product-license.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "54021411813"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

var recommendations = myFirebase.child("recommendations");


recommendations.push({
    "Id": id,
    "value": val,

});   
    }
</script>
    </head>
<body>
<form align="center">
        <input id="number" placeholder="Enter the Number"/>
    <br>
    <br>
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" onclick="fun()"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize firebase in first place then call `firebase.database().ref()`. Also you don't need double quotes in pushing maps values.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
    var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAw9IGgteG1Zis_oZ7t0V6xwgfJsiBMVZE",
    authDomain: "product-license.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://product-license.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "product-license",
    storageBucket: "product-license.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "54021411813"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

    function license() {
    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x100000)
      .toString(16)
      .substring(1);
  }
    var val=license();
    document.write(val);

    var myFirebase = firebase.database().ref();

    function fun(){
        var id = document.getElementById("number").value;

        var recommendations = myFirebase.child("recommendations");

        recommendations.push({
            Id: id,
            value: val,
        });   
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form align="center">
        <input id="number" placeholder="Enter the Number"/>
    <br>
    <br>
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" onclick="fun()"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```